How to rebase a child branch after its parent has been squashed, and can even disappear (for the child joining its parent-1)?
Here's was the development life:

I've started from a master branch, and created a feature branch.
feature = commits {a, b, c}

At a time, we were waiting for some specifications.
We decided to prepare a long term integration-tests for later use,
and being checkout -b from that feature.
The branches became: master <- feature {a,b,c} <- integration-tests {d,e}

if for any reason some {f, g} commits were coming in master

or that I add a h commit to feature, advancing a bit,


few rebase were putting things in order:
{master = master + {f,g}} <- feature {a,b,c,h} <- integration-tests {d, e}

At delivery time, like the usage is, it squashed my feature commits:
master <- feature {i = a+b+c+h} <- integration-tests {d, e}
merged that feature to master: {master = master + {i}}, pushed it, and everything was fine.
Except that I'm now in front of :
master <- feature {i} <- discording integration-tests {d, e}
who believes that it should be supported by a feature {a,b,c,h} and not the feature {i} it is seeing now.
And me, I would like it to stand that feature {i} for parent, at least
and more than that, if it's possible, to have now : master <- integration-tests {d, e}
What are the theoretical maneuvers to achieve this with Git?

You can do: git rebase last-commit-before-what-i-want-to-rebase the-branch-i-want-to-rebase --onto where-i-want-it-applied. So... only commits in range last-commit-before-what-i-want-to-rebase..the-branch-i-want-to-rebase will be rebased.

@eftshift0 What an impressive command! Thanks a lot!

git rebase? It's one of the crown-jewels, if you ask me.

And one of the super awesome options to rebase is --update-refs that lets you rebase multiple branches simultaneously!

Although, I must start by pointing out that squashing commits at the very end before delivering most likely is wrong and you should not do that.

However the following also applies to (interactive) rebases during development as well where for instance removing a temporary commit is perfectly fine.
So starting with the following history

then with integration-tests checked out you can run
git rebase --interactive --update-refs main

which brings up the following rebase todo list:
pick cd49c82 a
pick 35ab786 b
pick f314cbb c
pick 7df4873 h
update-ref refs/heads/feature

pick 7c87c2d d
pick 09a6066 e

(notice the embedded feature branch reference here)
If you than change this to
pick cd49c82 a
squash 35ab786 b
fixup f314cbb c
fixup 7df4873 h
update-ref refs/heads/feature

pick 7c87c2d d
pick 09a6066 e

and exit then git will rebase both integration-tests and feature in one operation, which is basically what you are asking for:

Update-refs can also be used for non-interactive rebases.

I'm squashing interactive at the end. But during the life of the development, it hardly can be done, else others developers will have trouble to synchronize. I do that only at the end or on my local commits only.
